# Is the access performance of __constant memory as same as __global memory on OpenCL

Tags: opencl

As I know. Constant memory on CUDA is a specific memory. And it is faster than global memory.
But in OpenCL's Spec. I get the following words.

> The `__constant` or constant address space name is used to describe variables allocated in global memory and which are accessed inside a kernel(s) as read-only variables

So the `__constant` memory is from the `__global` memory. Does that mean it have the same accessing performance with the `__global` memory?

Comment: Constant memory in the CUDA model *is* global memory, it is just accessed through a dedicated uniform cache.

Comment: Does the OpenCl implement it in the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the hardware and software architecture of the OpenCL platform you are using.  For example, one can envision an architecture with read-only caches that don't need to participate in cache coherency.  These caches could be used for constant memory but not global memory.  So you might see faster accesses to constant memory.

That being said, none of the architectures I'm familiar with operate this way.  So that's just hypothetical.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenCL standard does not specify how constant memory should be implemented, but in NVIDIA GPUs constant memory is cached. I don't know what AMD does.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this in 2022 (ten years after)...

**I have to !**

"
But in OpenCL's Spec. I get the following words.

```
The __constant or constant address space name is used to describe variables allocated in global memory and which are accessed inside a kernel(s) as read-only variables
```

So the __constant memory is from the __global memory. Does that mean it have the same accessing performance with the __global memory?
"

**CUDA and OpenCL**

**"__constant__"** memory is fast when all threads of a warp access the same memory address. Accessing other locations slows performance since access is then serialized. Some OpenCL FFT implementation used to have it's twiddle factors in a __constant__ memory but the access pattern (address) was thread id dependent. Hacking and binary editing the code was 60% faster on NVIDIA when saying just __global__ and two spaces instead of __constant__.