# Allocate a constant memory variable in local memory, only once, shared within its workgroup

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenCL application whose kernels all share two big chunks of constant memory. One of them is used to generate passwords, the other to test it.

The two subprograms are very fast when operating separately, but things slow to a halt when I run both of them one after the other (I have one quarter of the performances I would usually get).

I believe this is because the subroutine testing the passwords has a huge (10k) lookup table for AES decryption, and this isn't shared between multiple kernels running at the same time within the same workgroup.

I know it isn't shared because the AES lookup table is allocated as `__local` inside every single kernel and then initialised copying the values from an external library (as in, the kernel creates a local copy of the static memory and uses that).

I've tried changing the `__local` allocation/initialization to a `__constant` variable, a pointer pointing to the library's constant memory, but this gets me a **10x performance reduction**.

I can't make any sense of this. What should I do to make sure my constant memory is allocated only once per work group, and every kernel working in the same workgroup can share read operations there?

Comment: Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153443/is-the-access-performance-of-constant-memory-as-same-as-global-memory-on-ope) I believe constant memory is cached, not left in the same group as local memory, and I'm simply getting a big miss ration in the cache.

Comment: Constant memory is generally for broadcasting a variable to all threads simultaneously. Local memory is much better for random access or non-overlapping access but still effective at broadcasting. It seems your lookup table needs somewhat random looks by all threads. Besides, constant memory already serves the kernel constants of instructions.

Comment: Constant memory is a flag that might not be respected if the memory size is big, and it may not perform good depending on the pattern of accesses you have. Ideally constant should be used for small variables used by all threads in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__constant` memory by definition is shared by all work groups, so I would expect that in any reasonable implementation it is only allocated on the compute device once per kernel already.

On the other hand if you have two separate kernels that you are enqueueing back-to-back, I can't think of a reasonable way to guarantee that some `__constant` memory is shared or preserved on the device for both. If you want to be reasonably sure that some buffer is copied once to the compute device for use by both subroutines, then the subroutines should be a part of the same kernel.

In general, performance will depend on the underlying hardware & OpenCL implementation, and it will not be portable across different devices. You should see if there's an OpenCL performance guide for the hardware you are using.

As for *why* `__constant` memory may be slower than `__local` memory, again it depends on the hardware and how the OpenCL implementation maps address spaces to memory locations on the hardware. Your mistake is in assuming that `__constant` memory will be faster since it is by definition consistent. *Where* the memory is on the device will dictate how fast it is (i.e. a fast per-work-group buffer, vs a slower buffer shared by all work groups on the device) and the OpenCL address space is only one factor in how/where the OpenCL implementation will allocate memory. (Size matters also, and it's conceivable that if your `__constant` memory is small enough it will be "promoted" to faster per-work-group memory, but that totally depends on the implementation.)

If `__local` memory is faster as you say, then you might consider splitting up your work into work-group-sized chunks and passing in only that part of the table required by a work group to a `__local` buffer as a kernel parameter.